# Reversing a string in C++ using pointers

Tags: c++, string, pointers, reverse

```
void reverse(char[] x) {
    char* pStart = x;
    char* pEnd = pStart + sizeof(x) - 2;
    while(pStart < pEnd) {
        char temp = *pStart;
        *pStart = *pEnd;
        *pEnd = temp;
        pStart++;
        pEnd--;
    }
}

int main() {
    char text[] = ['h','e','l','l','o'];
    reverse(text);
    cout << text << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to C++ and stack overflow.

I am trying to reverse a string using pointers... I don't quite understand what I did wrong. Please help me out.

Additional question: What is the difference between a string and an array of characters?

Comment: A string is an object and is exactly what you should be using here.

Comment: "*What is the difference between a string and an array of characters?*" Assuming you're talking about an `std::string`, that's like asking the difference between a pocket calculator and a graphing calculator. They'll both give you the same numbers if you're fine writing a little more on paper to do the extra work, but if you were to offer me either one, I know which I'd take if my pocket is big enough.

Comment: Why not use `std::string s{"hello"}; std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());` ?

Comment: Warning: When using a common identifier like `reverse` be extra cautious if you choose to use `using namespace std;` There is already a `std::reverse` in the standard library and you can find yourself receiving some truly bizarre error messages or behaviour if the code comes into conflict with it.

Comment: @user4581301 shouldn't be an issue, since noone would be doing `using namespace std`, right?

Comment: @SergeyA Are you sure? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f47cd0b8ab81e89

Comment: A string is typically a null-terminated array of characters. The C and C++ standard library string handling functions use the null character at the end of the string to know when to stop. If you have an array that is not null terminated and attempt to use the library's string functions on it, Undefined Behaviour will occur, that is you don't know what will happen. You may get the expected result. You may not. But whatever you get, you can't typically count on it. Or maybe you can. Undefined is undefined.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not any more. I didn't realize brackets are all wrong. Sorry.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(x)` with `x` being a parameter of type `char[]` of a function does not give you the number of characters in the string but the size of a `char*`, probably `8` on a 64 bit system. You need to pass a C-String and use `strlen(x)` instead. Write `char text[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}` or `char text[] = "hello"` in `main`.

Note that `sizeof()` needs to be evaluatable at compile time; this is not possible on arrays with undetermined size like `char[]`-typed function arguments. When using `sizeof` on a variables like your `char text[] = {'h','e','l','l','o'}`, however, `sizeof(text)` will result in the actual size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

`char x[]` is the same as `char* x` and the `sizeof(x)` is therefore the size of a pointer. So, because you cannot calculate the size of an array outside of the block it is declared in, I would eliminate that part from your function.

It would be much easier to provide the function with pointers to the first and last characters to be replaced:

```
void reverse(char* pStart, char* pEnd)
{
    while (pStart < pEnd)
    {
        char temp = *pStart;
        *pStart   = *pEnd;
        *pEnd     = temp;
        pStart++;
        pEnd--;
    }
}
```

So now it is quite easy to call this function - take the address (using ampersand `&`) of the the relevant characters in the array: `&text[0]` and `&text[4]`.

To display an array of characters, there is a rule, that such "strings" HAVE to have after the last character a NULL character. A NULL character can be written as `0` or `'\0'`. That is why it has to be added to the array here.

```
int main()
{
    // char text[] = "hello"; // Same like below, also adds 0 at end BUT !!!in read-only memory!!
    char text[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
    reverse(&text[0], &text[4]);

    std::cout << text << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```